# JSON-code for more colors to use on pils in the choice-column

Tags: sharepoint-online

Does anyone know the JSON-code for using more colors on pils in the Choice-kolom.

Greetings, Peter Kiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can customize the color of the Choice column through the following JSON code:**

```
{  
  "elmType": "div",  
  "txtContent": "@currentField",  
  "style": {  
    "color": "#fff",  
    "padding-left": "14px",  
    "background-color": {  
      "operator": "?",  
      "operands": [  
        {  
          "operator": "==",  
          "operands": [  
            "@currentField",  
            "1"  
          ]  
        },  
        "#A9F5E1",  
        {  
          "operator": "?",  
          "operands": [  
            {  
              "operator": "==",  
              "operands": [  
                "@currentField",  
                "2"  
              ]  
            },  
            "#BCA9F5",  
            {  
              "operator": "?",  
              "operands": [  
                {  
                  "operator": "==",  
                  "operands": [  
                    "@currentField",  
                    "3"  
                  ]  
                },  
                "#FA58AC",  
                {  
                  "operator": "?",  
                  "operands": [  
                    {  
                      "operator": "==",  
                      "operands": [  
                        "@currentField",  
                        "4"  
                      ]  
                    },  
                    "#C8FE2E",  
                    ""  
                  ]  
                }  
              ]  
            }  
          ]  
        }  
      ]  
    }  
  }  
}
```

[image]

**Color code:** [HTML Color Chart](https://html-color-codes.info/)